# How to convert a PDF to JPG file and download it using PHP and dompdf

Tags: php, html, pdf, jpeg, dompdf

I have reduced my problem to a simplified code to make it easier to understand, so here we go.

The exact thing what I want is to download a JPG image pressing a button, but the thing is that image is created dynamically by the code, how? I'm using dompdf to create a PDF file from scratch HTML code so then I have to convert that PDF to JPG, but I don't know how to do it, here are some visual explanations and the code:

The simple HTML button which I use to call the file where the file is generated

[image]

The PDF file that it downloads when clicked

[image]

Here is the code I have:

The code of the button (ultrasimple)

button.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Button download</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <?php $name = "Mike"; ?>
        <button><a href="generate.php?name=<?php echo $name; ?>">BUTTON</a></button>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the code where the file is generated:

generate.php

```
<?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];
?>

<?php
    ob_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Generate file</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $name; ?>
    </body>
</html>

<?php

$html = ob_get_clean();

require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';

use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$dompdf = new Dompdf();

$options = $dompdf->getOptions();

$options->set(array('isRemoteEnabled' => true));

$dompdf->setOptions($options);

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream("file.pdf", array("Attachment" => true));

?>
```

(IMPORTANT: When I click the button it automatically download the PDF file and I want it to be the same but with that PDF converted to JPG)

So what I need is that when I click the button instead of downloading a PDF it must download a JPG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that, you could use Imagick - a native PHP extension, quick and simple for processing images.

```php
//first, define a file that you want to save as JPG image
$imgURL = 'tmp/NzgwYWIwMzZiOGNj.pdf';

//Process the file
$imagick = new Imagick();
$imagick->readImage($imgURL);
$imagick->writeImages('myimage.jpg', false);
```

This way you'll get your PDF file exported as JPG, page-by-page.
You can also fine-tune the above snippet, for example by adding SetResolution() method.
More on the matter can be found here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php